# Symfony2 and Doctrine2 Product & Images Mapping Not Efficient for Administration

Tags: php, orm, mapping, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony2 application I am supposed to have a product that should have multiple images but only one should be the main image which will identify the product between 20 or something products on one page. The rest of the images will be displayed when a user opens a specific product and all the product details about it appear including the rest of the images. Basically how most product sites work.

I have mapped it as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Productimage")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="productimage_map",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $images;    

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Product Images Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Webmuch\ShopBundle\Repository\ProductimageRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="productimage")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Productimage
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    protected $imagePath;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    */
    protected $created;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
    */      
    protected $mainImage;
}
```

It work alright, but when I create a form for creating a new item it shows a multiple select with all the rows of the Itemimage table. how do I make a system where I can just upload images from the item creation form itself and not select what images to map with the item from a multiple select form element containing 1000s of images.

I have also attached a image of what i'm trying to explain. Currently only has 2 images but they will become thousands in just a few hundred products.

I hope I have managed to explain what the problem is. This is very confusing to me. Please help me with this.

Also the multiple select elements show ids, I want them to be the titles. Any idea how I could do that as well?

Thanks! I appreciate all the help.

[image: cut out from the rendered form]

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `mainImage` property that references your images table directly instead of the Boolean flag you're using now.

You can specify you want the title of each image displayed by providing a `'property' => 'title'` option to the form type.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. The mainImage boolean is just to find out which image to use on other pages for identifying the product. For eg: in related items, on the homepage, on category page, etc. Also how do I add multiple images to one product without having to go through that multiple select form element. I wanna make  it simple to add an item with multiple images. First project this complex. Thanks again.